# How to redirect output to a specific file into a sed command?

Tags: shell, gcc, sed, makefile, io-redirection

Some context : I'm trying to build a generic Makefile, with auto-dependency generation (using GCC as described [here](http://make.mad-scientist.net/papers/advanced-auto-dependency-generation/#tldr), non recursive, which could be used from any level of my projects.
For that purpose, the dependency files generated need to be of the following form :

```
$(DIR)file.o: $(DIR)file.c $(DIR)file.h

$(DIR)file.h
```

That way, whatever the level of the make invocation, make can properly locate the files.

In order to do so, I have the following implicit rule :

```
DEPFLAGS = -MT $@ -MP -MMD -MF $(word 2,$^).tmp
COMPILE = $(CC) $(DEPFLAGS) $(CFLAGS) $(CPPFLAGS) -c -o $@ $<
POSTCOMPILE = sed -E 's|([0-9a-z_.:]*/)?([0-9a-z_.:]+)|$$(DIR)\2|g' $(word 2,$^).tmp > $(word 2,$^)

%.o: %.c %.dep
    $(COMPILE)
    $(POSTCOMPILE)
    $(RM) $(word 2,$^).tmp
    touch $@
```

The sed invocation replace any directory part before the filename by `$(DIR)`

The problem is that since the dependency file is generated after the object file, it causes the Makefile to relink every time. And so i have to add a touch command to be sure that the object file will be considered up-to-date. Which is not very elegant.
So I have this question : instead of using a temporary file, is there a way to directly redirect the gcc output (which is directed into the .tmp file) into the sed command ?

In others words, is there a way to do the equivalent of the pipe redirection, but for an other stream/file descriptor than stdout ?

Comment: in GNU sed there is `s/pattern/replacement/w file` which will write a substitution to a named file. You could use `s/.*/&/w yourFile`.

Comment: The answer to your question is no, there's no way to do that.  In any event, you'd need the `touch` anyway since there's no way to be 100% sure that the sed command would finish writing its file before the compiler finished writing the object file: they are running in parallel so you can't guarantee which one will finish first.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are in a full fledged linux environment, you can indeed skip the creation of the .tmp file and pipe the dependecies directly into `sed`.

```
# This is needed, because the default shell does not support
# process substitution
SHELL = /bin/bash

SED_COMMAND = sed -E 's|([0-9a-z_.:]*/)?([0-9a-z_.:]+)|$$(DIR)\2|g' > $(word 2,$^)
DEPFLAGS = -MT $@ -MP -MMD -MF >($(SED_COMMAND))
COMPILE = $(CC) $(DEPFLAGS) $(CFLAGS) $(CPPFLAGS) -c -o $@ $<

%.o: %.c %.dep
        $(COMPILE)
        touch $@
```

However, this still needs the `touch` command at the end, for the reason correctly mentioned in a comment by @MadScientist above:

> there's no way to be 100% sure that the sed command would finish writing its file before the compiler finished writing the object file: they are running in parallel so you can't guarantee which one will finish first.

Comment: Thxs, that was exactly what I was searching (despite the fact that I will still need to touch the file). Is that specific to Linux, or to Bash ? (I work on Linux and MacOs, since my school use Macs).

Comment: Process substitution is a bash-specific construct available only in some environments: desktop Linux and MacOS are among them.